# Permission to CocoaPods/Specs.git denied

Tags: git, github, cocoapods

Currently getting the following error when I'm trying to do a push.

```
git:(swift3) git push --set-upstream origin swift3
remote: Permission to CocoaPods/Specs.git denied to paul301.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

This all started when I moved from .36 to version 1.0.1

I've tried reinstalling CocoaPods, removing all the CocoaPods files in the project (worksapce, podfile, pod folder, podfile.lock) and doing a fresh 'pod init', clearing CocoaPods caches and a number of other things.

It seems like its trying to push my commits to the Specs repo. I've been noticing "pod install" has been changing my git repot to point to the specs repo:

[image]

My Podfile:

```
platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'Test' do
  use_frameworks!
  pod 'Moya', '8.0.0-beta.2'
  pod 'iCarousel'
  pod 'ObjectMapper', '~> 2.0'
  pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.0'
  pod 'FacebookCore'
  pod 'FacebookLogin'

end
```

Comment: So why is Cocoapods changing the git `origin` on `pod install`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have the same bug I just change to cocoa pod to 1.0.1...

basically your `origin` have been changed to `https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git`

you can check with:

```
➜  git:(new_version) git remote -vv
origin  https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git (push)
```

you can change this either through terminal or modify the file manually

Terminal:

```
git remote set-url origin https://github.com/PSEUDO/NAME_OF_YOUR_GIT.git
```

**or**, go into `.git\config` file and change

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = https://github.com/PSEUDO/NAME_OF_YOUR_GIT.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

to

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = https://github.com/PSEUDO/NAME_OF_YOUR_GIT.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

Comment: mind blown... why updating cocoa pods would do that is incredible.

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out "pod install" actually did change my git. As can be seen in my git config the url was changed to https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git, which I changed back to point to my git repo and all was fixed

```
➜  .git git: cd .git 
➜  .git git: cat config
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    ignorecase = true
    precomposeunicode = true
[remote "origin"]
    url = https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
```

Comment: I had the same issue, took me all day to figure out! Came here to confirm that yes "pod install" or "pod update" wrote over my git origin to the CocoaPods spec url as well.